# How to format "2pm" to "2:00 PM" using Moment.js?

Tags: node.js, momentjs

I need to parse "2pm" (for example) from an input element, which eases the user to just type "2pm" or "4am" or whatever they like and get it formatted to "2:00 PM" or "4:00 PM".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```js
const moment  = require('moment')
const dateFormated = moment('Mon 03-Apr-2017, 2AM', 'ddd DD-MMM-YYYY, hh A').format('hh:mm A')
console.log(dateFormated)
```

The console log result will be `02:00 AM`

The `.format()` will define the input you wish to get.
This is the main direction you should go through.